# How to turn off NewsStand featur form itunes connect or xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have created application in iTunes connect. While creating app i by mistake turn on NewsStand feature on.
Now when i upload binary to iTunes i get error which tells me to create auto renewal product.
I don't want to add any unnecessary product into my app. So how can I turn NewsStand off or disable it from iTunes or via xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in itune connect, select app detail, then there is a button/link to disable it.

Comment: I am having the same problem but unable to disable it. can you please describe the steps in detail